# ckan 2.9 allow only certain filetypes on upload

Tags: ckan

Even this question sounds like a common use case I cannot find any docs how to archive the following:

How can I define which file types are allowed for upload with cKAN 2.9.
(Currently, it's possible to upload nearly everything.)

Comment: I think there is no way unless you develop a plugin to add this behavior to ckan. Like using `ckan.plugins.interfaces.IResourceController` that has a `before_create` function that you can implement and extend. https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you need validation for the filestore or datastore too? As far as I know, you can limit the file formats when uploading to the Datastore by setting up the

```
ckan.datapusher.formats = csv or xlsx
```

You can find the default supported formats in the [datapusher settings](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/maintaining/configuration.html?highlight=xml#datapusher-settings).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But this will only consider datapusher. Still users could upload a binary file like some *. exe